# dial a ride algorithm implementation using Jsprit

Tags: jsprit

I have a task to implement Dial-A-Ride scenario. As of now, the option available with me is to use Jsprit.
I found the following link on the [github wiki](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/wiki/Dial-a-ride-problem) of Jsprit

But I am not able to exactly figure out what **"probably you want the shipment to have a capacity-demand of 1"** means.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with a dial-a-ride problem like pickup someone and bring him to a specific destination you usually do not have unlimited capacities in your car or bus. Let me assume you have four seats, then the capacity of your car is four; and you need to define it like that. Every person that is picked up consumes one unit of your car's capacity, i.e. one seat. This is what is meant with "probably you want the shipment to have a capacity-demand of 1". The request that your person need to be moved from A to B can be modeled as shipment with a capacity demand of 1.

Comment: considering that the vehicle as a capacity of 1 only. The problem is that in Dial-a-ride problem, once a pickup has been done, it has to be delivered before another pickup. But in pickup-delivery model multiple pickups are possible simultaneously. By defining the capacity-demand as 1 would the requirement be fulfilled ?

Comment: You need to differentiate between the capacity of the vehicle and the capacity-demand of your jobs. Multiple pickups are possible if you assign a capacity demand of 1 to your jobs AND a capacity of > 1 to your vehicle.

Comment: so, in my scenario should I set "capacity demand as 1" and capacity also 1